# Error on Render function

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, render, react-proptypes

I get an error "Nothing was returned from render.This usually means a return statement is missing.Or, to render nothing, return null." 
I guess its something to do with the type in My TimelineCard.I think the type is not set or perhaps, but I cant figure out where exactly.
On ios I don׳t get the same mistake, only on android.I am attaching my Render function.

My TimelineCard:

```
renderInfoBar(width, item) {
        let dotSize = 6;

    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        return (
            <View style={{width: width - 80, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: Colors.white}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
                    <Text style={{marginRight: 0, marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: Colors.darkText}}>{numeral(item.likes).format('0,0')} likes</Text>
                    <View style={{width: dotSize, height: dotSize, backgroundColor: Colors.darkText, borderRadius: 25, marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10}}></View>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: Colors.darkText}}>{numeral(item.shares.length).format('0,0')} shares</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', marginTop: 0}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: Colors.darkText}}>{numeral(item.views).format('0,0')}</Text>
                    <Image source={require("../assets/images/views-icon.png")} style={{marginRight: 10, marginLeft: 5}}/>
                </View>
            </View>                                                         
        );  
    }
    else {
        return (
            <View style={{width: width - 80, height: 30, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: Colors.white}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', marginTop: 2}}>
                    <Text style={{marginRight: 0, marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: Colors.darkText}}>{numeral(item.likes).format('0,0')} likes</Text>
                    <Entypo name="dot-single" style={{marginTop: -7}} size={32} color={Colors.darkText} />                          
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: Colors.darkText}}>{numeral(item.shares.length).format('0,0')} shares</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', marginTop: 0, marginBottom: 7}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: Colors.darkText}}>{numeral(item.views).format('0,0')}</Text>
                    <Image source={require("../assets/images/views-icon.png")} style={{marginRight: 10, marginLeft: 5}}/>
                </View>
            </View>                                                         
        );  
    }
}

render() {

let {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

let containerStyle = {flex: 1, marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 20};

if (this.state.rowData.type === PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PERMISSION_DECLINED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PERMISSION_CANCELED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_VIEWED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_LIKED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_UNLIKED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_SHARED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotificationWithFullPhoto(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_COMMENTED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )   
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_TAGGED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_NOTED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_CREATED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotificationWithFullPhoto(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )                                 
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_SCREENSHOT_CAPTURE) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
else if (this.state.rowData.type === PHOTO_UNSHARED) {
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            {this.renderNotification(this.state.rowData)}
        </View>
    )           
}
```

}

Comment: like @Khoa said. You need to add else so you can see what is missing: `else {console.log(this.state.rowData.type);}` or `else {return (<View><Text>{this.state.rowData.type}</Text></View>})}` ( to print it on screen)

Comment: @gaback your suggestion works on else {return (<View><Text>{this.state.rowData.type}</Text></View>})} . As I asked Khoa, I would like to get some farther explanation , so I will understand it better, because I didn't write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the suggestion is clear:

> Or, to render nothing, return null.

You need to add the last `else` (not `else if`) with `return null;`

You may be missing 1 case => let add a `console.log` before `return null` to check what it is.

Comment: Hi Khoa, thanks for the suggestion ,I added else{return(null);} , and it works. Would you mind to explain farther the logic behind, I didn't write the code , therefore I am not much familiar  how it works.thank you

Comment: @IlonaSemyonov: The `render` function was expected to return a `Component` or `null`. The old code returned `Component` for each case of `if` or `else if`. What if the `type` of `rowData` does not match all above cases => there is nothing return. To prevent that situation, we add 1 more `else` clause to handle all unexpected cases. The `else` clause will capture all of the rest cases.